# Is it possible to disable null safety for a dependent Dart package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm trying to build app using hive but the hive_flutter package doesn't supporting null safety.

Is there any way to turn off null safety for this package only or is there any alternative for the hive_flutter package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Migrating to null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide), all your dependencies must be migrated to null safety first:

> Here are the basic steps for migrating each package that you own:
>
> 1. Wait for the packages that you depend on to migrate.
> 2. ...
>
> Migrating an app is technically the same as migrating a package. Before migrating an app, make sure that all of your dependencies are ready.

But `hive_flutter` [supports null safety](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter/versions) since version 1.0.0 (March 5 2021). So you should simply upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off null safety, change sdk environment in ***pubspec.yaml*** to this:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```